# Forcing <table> Columns to a Fixed Width; Prevent Automatic Expand

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, width, multiple-columns

I generally set fixed column widths via CSS with flawless results:

```
#tableID thead tr th:nth-child(1){width: 75px;} 
#tableID thead tr th:nth-child(2){width: 75px;}
/* etc… */
```

But now I'm in a situation where I won't know the desired column widths until runtime. Here's an excerpt from the code I'm using to dynamically set the column widths:

```
var tr=$("<tr>");
var colArr=Home.ColDefs[this.statBatchType].colArr;
for(var i=0;i<colArr.length;i++){
    var col=colArr[i];
    tr.append(
        $("<th>")
            .html(col.title)
            .css("width",col.width)
    );
}
this.jqTHead.append(tr);
```

Sorry this code is a bit out of context but the bottom line is that I'm adding columns, represented by `<th>` elements, to a table header and setting each one's width.

What ACTUALLY happens, however, is that Firefox is treating the column width as a minimum and then automatically expanding the column width as the user expands his browser window. Consider a case where my JavaScript code sets the width of each column to 75px. Firefox will ensure each column is at least 75px wide, but if the user maximizes (or enlarges) his browser,  provided there is sufficient room, each column will be automatically widened.

This is odd to me since the JavaScript code would seem to be the functional equivalent of what I was doing in CSS. Yet the CSS approach doesn't cause this odd behavior.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have widths applied to the table?

Comment: You could set max-with: 75px;

Comment: I think you can define column width using a `colgroup` and setting styles on the `col` tags

Comment: epascarello: no, table fills up entire width (100%). Is this my problem? Bertrand: good idea. I considered that but was still confused by existing behaviour.

Comment: @ChadDecker, Fix the widths of your tables too.

Comment: Can you add a JSfiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

Fix the width of the `<table>` this will ensure the table does not take the available size and bump the layout.

Answer (score 1):

[`table-layout: fixed;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) on the table does exactly this: columns never expand to fit their contents, and if you give the table itself a width, the extra space is divided equally.  The contents of cells don't come into play at all.

Comment: I double checked the Computed Style tab to ensure that table-layout:fixed applied to the table. It did. I even tried setting "maxWidth" (in addition to "width") to the appropriate value. It doesn't help. When the browser is enlarged, the inspector shows that the width of the <th> elements actually exceed their maxWidth.

Comment: well, um, that doesn't make a lot of sense  :)  nothing else funny going on?  can you make a reduced test case and stick it on jsfiddle?